# Want to extract $$text$$ only

Tags: java, regex

I have to extract exactly $$anytext$$ words from a paragraph. I wrote a regex pattern but it's not exactly do what I want.

```
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$\\$\\S*?\\$\\$").matcher(originalContent);
```

Consider the following example paragraph.

My text is this $$testtt$$ no need to extract $$$this$$.

My regex patter will extract,
$$testtt$$ , $$$this$$

but what I want to extract is,
$$testtt$$, $$this$$

my regex fail when there is more than two $$ signs. I want to extract exactly two dollar signs before and last. $$text$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following version:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\${2}[^\\s$]*\\${2}").matcher(originalContent);
```

### Demo

Comment: this will only extract $$testtt$$. I want to extract $$testtt$$ and $$this$$

Comment: [My pattern is working for your examples](https://regex101.com/r/Lc1kcY/3).

Comment: @user9353766 - in the [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Lc1kcY/3) page select **Code Generator** in the left pane then select **Java**.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP's example is actually *"My text is this $$testtt$$ no need to extract $$$this$$"*. OP wants `$$this$$` out of `$$$this$$`, so remove the `(?<!\\$)` and `(?!\\$)` negative lookarounds, since that's not what OP wants. --- Also, OP's attempt used `\\S`, i.e. no whitespace between the markers, but your `[^$]` allows whitespace, so you should use `[^$\\s]`.

Comment: @Andreas Answer updated, but your reading of the question strikes me as a somewhat unusual requirement.

Comment: It's what OP wants. The question is, did OP want to match `$$foo$bar$$` in `$$$$foo$bar$$$$`? Technically, the question might allow it, but your current solution won't. Guess only OP can say. I believe your solution is good, so +1 from me.